# INNER JOIN Count Unknown column in ON clause

Tags: sql, inner-join

I'm using HeidiSQl and trying to run a query where I get all the users from table 1 and then count all the matching users in table 2.

```
SELECT DISTINCT problem, title, username, createdate, expiredate
FROM solutionhistory as table1
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(LOGIN_NAME) FROM ra_report_table) as table2
ON table1.username=table2.LOGIN_NAME
WHERE username != 'test'
LIMIT 10
```

I'm a bit stuck as to where I'm going wrong! I'm getting the error unknown column in on clause for `table2.LOGIN_NAME`.

The query works if I take the reference to `COUNT(LOGIN_NAME)` out - if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(LOGIN_NAME)` will create a column called `COUNT(LOGIN_NAME)`. You should alias the columns in future (and then do what @GordonLinoff says)

Comment: HeidiSQL is not a DBMS, only a SQL client. Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query doesn't make sense on a lot of levels.  I am guessing you intend something more like this:

```
SELECT problem, title, username, createdate, expiredate, table2.cnt
FROM solutionhistory as table1 INNER JOIN
     (SELECT LOGIN_NAME, COUNT(LOGIN_NAME) as cnt
      FROM ra_report_table
      GROUP BY LOGIN_NAME
    ) as table2
    ON table1.username = table2.LOGIN_NAME
WHERE username <> 'test'
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: That sorted it! Thank you!